# How to make advanced windows 8.1 installation disc (like Toshiba windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, windows-installation

I want to make my advanced Windows installation image / disc for easy installation, like Toshiba does.

Comment: Its not clear what you are talking about.  What exactly makes the installation media advanced?

Comment: @Ramhound I think they mean like the customized recovery images most manufacturers include in a hidden partition. So that, should the user decide to reimage the system, they get an OOBE with all the applications that came originally pre-installed. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @JSanchez understood my idea. Simply i want to make my own cd like manufacturers does.

Comment: Like this? http://serverfault.com/questions/289085/pre-configured-bootable-windows-installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install a fresh Windows, but [go into audit mode before OOBE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824920.aspx) with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

Now install all Software you want to include. When you have done this, run [`sysprep /generalize`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824938.aspx) to make the Image usable on all hardware configurations.

Now capture the installation to a new Image (WIM) with DISM:

```
Dism /Capture-Image /ImageFile:D:\Install.wim /CaptureDir:C:\ /Compress:maximum
```

replace the original Install.wim with your one.

Comment: your answer is very good but it still i don't know how to change windows loading logo (by saying that i mean logo in this srcean http://0.tqn.com/d/pcsupport/1/0/S/H/-/-/windows-8-clean-install-03.png). and i already know hot to enter audit mode

Comment: this can be only changed by hacking files which is not recommend.